# Error in implementation of multiple for loops

Tags: c, overflow, numerical-methods, newtons-method

In this program I have to find the root of the function using `Newton-Raphson` method. For every value of `r` I need to find `R`, `f0` then I find the root.

After which I want to increment the value of `r` and find the root again till `r<=10`. I am able to find the root for initial value of `"r=1"` but I am not able to increment value of `r` to find roots for other values of `r` till `10`. The loop is getting exited after first step.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define w 0.10655
#define z -9.208
#define allerr 0.000001
#define maxiter 100

float f(float f,float r,float R)
{
    return w*f-z*(r-1)+r*log(pow(r,1.5)*(r-f*f));
}
float df (float f,float r,float R)
{
    return w-(2*r*f/(r-f*f));
}
int main()
{
    int itr;
    float h, f0, f1,r,R;

    for(r=1; r<=10; r+=0.1)
    {
        R=pow(r,-2.5)*exp(z*((r-1)/r));
        f0=w*R+(sqrt(w*w*R*R+(2*r*(r-R))*(2*r+R*w*w/r)))/((2*r+R*w*w)/r);
        for (itr=1; itr<=maxiter; itr++)
        {
            h=f(f0,r,R)/df(f0,r,R);
            x1=f0-h;
            printf(" At Iteration no. %3d, x = %9.6f\n", itr, x1);
            if (fabs(h) < allerr)
            {
                printf("After %3d iterations, root = %8.6f\n", itr, x1);
                return 0;
            }
            f0=x1;
        }

        printf(" The required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: What are all those variables and functions (or worse macros) you don't show us? What are their types? What are their values? What are their implementations? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Why are you "not able to incremet value of r"? Incrementing a variable is one of the easiest operations in most programming languages

Comment: Not your problem, but `for(r=1;r<=10;r+=0.1)` is likely to give you an unwanted extra trip through the loop.

Comment: We need http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help you.

Comment: This is the full code that i have written .I am not able to understand why the program is exiting  the for loop when both  the condition are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A housekeeping first.

**1)** Your posted code is missing closing bracket. The variable `x1` is not defined.

**2)** There is no reason to use `float` variables. Use `double` for better precision.

**3)** To exit inner loop nicely do not use `return` just break it with `break`. The control will be given to the outer loop. Do not use `return` outside the loop either.

**4)** Distinguish leaving the inner loop via `break` (when solution was found) from the case where the maximum number of iterations was reached. (This can be done via `sfound` flag.)

**5)** No need to flood the printout with intermediate steps.

**6)** Improve the printout to include `r` value.

**7)** A note: your numerical Newton-Raphson  method is not stable for your functions.

The code below solves the reported problem of not executing the `r` loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define w            0.10655
#define z             -9.208
#define allerr      0.000001
#define maxiter         1000

double f(double f, double r, double R)
{
    return w*f-z*(r-1)+r*log(pow(r,1.5)*(r-f*f));
}

double df (double f, double r, double R)
{
    return w-(2.0*r*f/(r-f*f));
}

int main(void)
{
    int itr;
    double h, f0, f1, r, R, x1;
    int sfound = 0;

    for(r=1.0; r<=10.0; r+=0.1)
    {
        sfound = 0;  

        R = pow(r,-2.5)*exp(z*((r-1)/r));

        f0 = w*R+(sqrt(w*w*R*R+(2*r*(r-R))*(2*r+R*w*w/r)))/((2*r+R*w*w)/r);

        for (itr=1; itr <= maxiter; itr++)
        {
            h = f(f0,r,R)/df(f0,r,R);

            x1 = f0 - h;

            // printf(" r=%.2f at Iteration no. %3d, x = %9.6f\n", r, itr, x1);

            if (fabs(h) < allerr)
            {
                printf("For r=%.2f after %3d iterations, root = %8.6f\n", r,  itr, x1);
                sfound = 1;
                break; 
            }

            f0 = x1;
        }
        if(sfound == 0)
            printf("For r=%.2f the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient\n",r);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
For r=1.00 after   5 iterations, root = 0.105951                                                                                               
For r=1.10 after   5 iterations, root = 0.868910                                                                                               
For r=1.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=1.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=2.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=3.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=4.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=5.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=6.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient   
For r=7.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=7.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=8.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.10 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.20 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.30 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.40 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.50 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.60 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.70 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.80 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=9.90 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient                                                              
For r=10.00 the required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient
```

Comment: When I calculated for each value of r it actually converged and I was able to find the solution . And how can we make the code stable

Comment: @SudhirKumar  "When I calculated for each value of `r` it actually converged" How did you calculate it? How do you know that it converged? Are you sure  that your function here `f` and `df` are actually correct?

Comment: When I calculated individually for each value of r  i find R and f0.i put these values into function to get root .For every value of r i was able to find the root.Yes the equations i have put in the function f and df are correct.

Comment: @SudhirKumar  No, something must be wrong! Check again all functions . Even, if you calculate one value here e.g. `for(r=2.0; r<=2.0; r+=0.1)` the the required solution does not converge.

Comment: hai thank you, the function used for calculating the f0 has an error while i was entering it.Now it converges the for all the values i have entered.

Comment: yeah,Thank you very much